# exe generated by pyinstaller doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I use pyinstaller to convert my py to exe. It contains a UI written by tkinter.

```
pyinstaller -F my_tool.py
```

The exe runs normally on my own computer (UI appears in 1-2 min), but when I send it to others, it takes very long time (>15min) to display the UI.

I have no idea of why this happens and how to make the exe respond quickly in other computers. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

---Edit---

I found some warnings in the log and I'm wondering whether the warnings impact the exe:

```
62194 WARNING: Hidden import "importlib_resources.trees" not found!
62446 WARNING: Conda distribution 'numpy', dependency of 'numpy', was not found. If you installed this distribution with pip then you may ignore this warning.
76721 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
76721 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
```

I checked the packages in the env and I have installed numpy, importlib_resources. For pkg_resources, pip throws no matching distribution error.

I also found that the suffix of the output file is '.exe.notanexecutable', not '.exe'.

```
125205 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\XinDong\Documents\tool\dist\tool.exe.notanexecutable
...
125615 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\XinDong\Documents\AP_TST\tool\dist\tool.exe.notanexecutable
```

Comment: The filename being `.exe.notanexecutable` is just to stop antivirus programs causing PyInstaller to crash by trying to scan the files mid-build. You can ignore the warnings you posted, too. 

How big is the file generated with PyInstaller?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. The exe generated with 'one file' mode is about 32M.

Comment: If the onefile executable is 32M then no wonder it's taking them a while to load it; onefile is just a onedir build compressed & appended to the onefile executable, the extracted at runtime & run.

Comment: I'd recommend building it in onedirectory mode and packaging it with a tool such as Innosetup or NSIS.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem but I figured it out. try using the cd function to change your directory to C:\Users\XinDong\Documents\tool\dist then try it again and if that doesn't work use this method: pyinstaller --onefile my_tool.py instead of pyinstaller -F my_tool.py

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yout could use auto-py-to-exe. Thats works for me fine(uses pyinstaller as well). It may add a few parameters that could fix your problem(not shure).

It would be interesting to know what modules your code uses and if it creates a database or so.

Maybe the other pc is just lackin hardware.

PS: Sorry, for using answer. I do not have the reputation for comments yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I tried auto-py-to-exe too but it didn't help. I just import some commonly used modules such as pandas, requests, date, styleframe and tkinter(for UI).

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your pyinstaller, then install it from the following link
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
most likely, the problem is solved